# Is there a relationship between the Jacobian at a point and the curvature at that point?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

The Jacobian $J$ For a dynamical system $\dot{\textrm{x}}=F(\textrm{x})$ determines the dynamics in the tangent plane at a given point. Intuitively speaking the Jacobian evaluated at a point should contain some information about the curvature at that point but I don't know of any such association. Sorry for the vague phrasing of the question, I lack sufficient training to make this more precise.

Comment: What kind of curvature are you referring to, in the absence of a metric or a connection? And do you know the theorem stating that every nonzero vector field is locally a coordinate vector field?

Comment: I'm wondering whether the Jacobian (or some transformation) contains any information about the local curvature. No, I wasn't aware of that theorem. Looking it up now!

Comment: One reference for the theorem that every nonzero vector field is locally a coordinate field is an early chapter of F. Warner's book *Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups*

Comment: @user9563: But what do you actually mean by curvature? The usual notion of curvature is the curvature of a connection, but it's not clear which connection you'd be referring to in your context.

Comment: curvature of what ?

Comment: @TobiasFritz Thanks for making me think about it a little more. I mean the curvature one would get by doing parallel transport around a point.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Curvature of the manifold that the trajectories lie on. So for example if the trajectories of $\dot{\textrm{x}}=F(\textrm{x})$ lie on a torus then does the Jacobian evaluated at a point $\textrm{x}_i$ (or some transformation) contain any information about the curvature obtained by doing parallel transport around $\textrm{x}_i$.

Comment: @user9563: So your manifold is Riemannian or otherwise comes equipped with a connection? Then the answer is no, the Jacobian does not tell you anything about the curvature, since you have not assumed anything about how $F$ relates to the geometry. If you don't assume anything, then you also can't conclude anything.

Comment: @TobiasFritz I see, thank you for the answer (and your patience). I want to understand more what you meant by "since you have not assumed anything about how $F$ relates to the geometry". Can you give an example of how $F$ can relate to the geometry? Like when $F$ is derived from a Hamiltonian?

Comment: @user9563: Exactly, $F$ being a Hamiltonian vector field on a symplectic manifold would be one possible relation to a geometrical structure. However, since a symplectic manifold doesn't have any notion of curvature, again your question doesn't really make sense in this case. Perhaps you should elaborate on how your question came up and what application you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know anything about symplectic manifolds so I am a little confused. Talking simple mindedly, the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$ describes a circle in the phase space. But the circle has curvature right? $\frac {1}{R}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} H}$ in this case. 
As for the context of my question. I'm interested in analyzing geometrical properties of real world dynamical systems, from some experimental data I can reconstruct a phase space (Takens embedding), and can estimate local Jacobians. So I was wondering under what conditions can I also extract the curvature?

Comment: The circle has curvature only because you're thinking of it as embedded in Euclidean space. This concept of curvature is not invariant under symplectic (=canonical) transformations, and therefore is not something that you can talk about at the level of symplectic manifolds.

Comment: Concerning the Takens embedding, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takens%27_theorem states explicitly that it "does not preserve the geometric shape of structures in phase space". Hence whatever notion of curvature you use for the embedding manifold, it will not reflect the geometrical properties of real-world dynamical systems that you're after.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry I couldn't explain myself properly there. I'm actually interested in the Euler characteristic, and I was wondering if there's a way to use the Gauss-bonnet theorem to get at that, for which I would need an estimate of local curvature. That's the full story. Thinking about this just made me wonder how much information about the local curvature can be extracted from the estimated Jacobian.